# Call variadic templated function with arguments from a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I need to convert elements of a std::vector to types based on a template parameter and call a function with these parameters. In pseudocode:

```
template <typename T...>
void foo(std::vector<std::string> v) {
    if (v.size() != sizeof...(T))
        throw std::runtime_error("Bad");

    bar(convert<T0>(v[0]), convert<T1>(v[1]), ..., convert<Tn>(v[n]));
}
```

My problem is how to obtain the element indices from the parameter pack, I think there will be some kind of a trick using fold expressions, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, types (here the variadic template param size) can't depend on runtime values (here the size of the vector). This is only possible if you know the max vector size, by using templates to pre-generate boilerplate to call the function with up to N arguments.

Comment: I assume that the vector size is equal to parameter pack size and that it is checked at runtime, before the magic happens. It seemed obvious to me, so I didn't mention it. My bad :). I've edited the code to include the check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know that the number of elements in a vector is equal to the parameter pack size, you can solve this problem by adding one level of indirection:

```
template<typename... T, std::size_t... is>
void foo_impl(const std::vector<std::string>& v, std::index_sequence<is...>) {
    bar(convert<T>(v[is])...);
}


template<typename... T>
void foo(const std::vector<std::string>& v) {
    assert(v.size() == sizeof...(T));
    foo_impl<T...>(v, std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
}
```

The idea here is to expand two packs, `Ts...` and `is...`, which have equal sizes, simultaneously.

---

C++20 solution:

```
template<typename... T>
void foo(const std::vector<std::string>& v) {
    assert(v.size() == sizeof...(T));

    [&v]<std::size_t... is>(std::index_sequence<is...>) {
        bar(convert<T>(v[is])...);
    }(std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could solve this by using an [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to access the elements of the vector.

```
namespace detail
{
template <typename...T, size_t...I>
void foo(std::vector<std::string>& v, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    bar(convert<T>(v[I])...);
}
}

template <typename...T>
void foo(std::vector<std::string>& v) {
    if (v.size() != sizeof...(T))
        throw std::runtime_error("Bad");
    detail::foo<T...>(v, std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
}
```

On Godbolt: [Link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/347aoPKaP)